# How to make the navigation icon open a dropdown menu onclick? (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, onclicklistener, android-drawable

So, I know it might be a very simple question however I found only very ugly solution to the problem, therefore I'm turning to you.

I have an actionbar as the following:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp">

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I simply couldn't find any normal way causing the sandwich icon to open a small dropdown menu of options once being clicked.

Thanks to the helpers!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add menu code for that like this in activity class file,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Get menu inflater.
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();

    // Use app bar layout menu to inflate the tool bar.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_name, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```